# How to determine proper driver for DELL Latitude?

Tags: drivers, external-display, dell-latitude, diagnostic

I have a DELL Latitude notebook with Win10 running on it. OS and drivers have latest version and also the video driver origins from the graphic chhip vendor.
The problem I have with the notebook is that when I connect it to external monitor, the monitor shows very unclear image in red colors. The internal display works normally.
I tried switching some graphics settings but nothing helps. The monitor has no issues.

How can I determine the proper graphics driver for that notebook?
Is there a software tool that scans the hardware components and recommends the driver to use?

Comment: Did you try Dell's Driver Update App?

Comment: Why are you assuming the issue is drivers? Have you tried different cables, a different monitor?

Comment: Usually, drivers work... or they don't, **at all**. A blurry, red image is almost certainly **not** a driver issue.